# How can I detect when user clicks outside of input box (cursor goes away)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

blur does the job on Safari, but on Firefox it is causing problems. It seems that blur on Firefox fires when the mouse is moved outside of the input box, not when the cursor is actually removed (like when a user clicks somewhere outside of the box). This is a problem for me because I don't want my code to fire just because the user's cursor is moved outside of the box... I only want it to fire when the user clicks outside of the box as to indicate they are done typing. I have even tried event focusout but the same problem happens. Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="min-reward-amount-input">Minimum reward amount</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
        <input type="number" step="0.1" min="0" class="form-control" id="min-reward-amount-input" placeholder="0.00">
    </div>
</div>


$("#min-reward-amount-input").blur(function(){
    var initialValue = parseFloat($("#min-reward-amount-input").val());
    if(!isNaN(initialValue) && initialValue>=0) {
        var processedValue = initialValue.toFixed(2);
        $("#min-reward-amount-input").val(processedValue);

    } else {
        $("#min-reward-amount-input").val("0.00");
    }
});
```

Comment: `It seems that blur on Firefox fires when the mouse is moved outside of the input box` - Firefox doesn't behave that way for me - in this fiddle of your code https://jsfiddle.net/wf84tcwd/

Comment: Hmm interesting. Maybe bootstrap is causing a problem. I added my code with the input.

Comment: interestingly, when using your HTML, i.e. the input type is number, firefox still triggers blur at the correct time (i.e. when the input loses focus) - but the number is not updated to have 2 decimal digits

Comment: That is a problem I was also getting. When blur fired it would completely disregard that I wanted to format to 2 decimal places =/

Comment: wow, firefox number inputs are quite "interesting" in many respects!

Comment: attach a click event handler to the document.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, I'd do something like this using eventListeners:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (event.target.className !== "textBox") {
        window.alert("Clicked outside input field");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="textBox_1" class="textBox" placeholder="Field 1" />
<input type="text" name="textBox_2" class="textBox" placeholder="Field 2" />
<input type="text" name="textBox_3" class="textBox" placeholder="Field 3" />

<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Next" />
</form>
```

Though there might, and probably is more elegant solutions instead of looking at the className.